# SSRS Multivalued parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report in ssrs 2008 r2.I have created two multi-valued parameter on my report like fiscal period (value is 08,09,10,11) and parentname(in which there are multiple parent like a,b,c,d...).A user can select single value  or multiple value of his choice.I have create seprate dataset for each to populate its value.Both have datatype 'Text'.

Now uderlying query is something like this:

```
selet * from table where fiscal period in(@fiscalperiod) and parentname in(@parentname)
```

If I run this query manually in sql then I wrote query like

```
select * from table where fiscalperiod in('09','10') and parentname in('a','b''c')
```

Now my question is Is ssrs run the dataset query of report in this way like 'a','b''c' that means comma seprated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Parameter is  multi-valued, Query will be run like 'a','b','c'

```
selet * from table where fiscal period in(@fiscalperiod) and parentname in(@parentname)
```

If you select fiscal period: 08, 09 and parentname: a, b then query will be executed internally like

```
selet * from table where fiscal period in('08', '09') and parentname in('a', 'b')
```